# How do I add a css class when using new ListItem on databound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, listitem

I am adding some values to a drop down list using a loop:

```
for (Int32 i = 1; i <= MaxOrderQuantity; i++)
{
    myDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(i), Convert.ToString(i)));
}
```

I want to add a CSS attribute to the new ListItem at the same time. I have seen I can use

```
.Attributes.Add("class","foo")
```

However the only way I can find to do it is by breaking down my single line of code in to 3 separate lines of code like this:

```
ListItem newListItem = new ListItem("my value", "my value");
newListItem.Attributes.Add("class", "blah");
myDropDownList.Items.Add(newListItem);
```

The intellisense allowed me to write the following code but it errors and says "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments.

```
myDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(i), Convert.ToString(i)).Attributes.Add("class","blah"));
```

How is it possible to add a new ListItem with a 'class' attribute in a single line of code?

Comment: The problem here is *NOT* that you *MUST* write this in one line of code to get it to work. There is a logical error, do a console writeline for all the elements and check where the error lies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, because Attributes.Add() does not return a ListItem object.

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.attributecollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_AttributeCollection_Add_System_String_System_String_

You can either use the old way

```
ListItem newListItem = new ListItem("my value", "my value");
newListItem.Attributes.Add("class", "blah");
myDropDownList.Items.Add(newListItem);
```

or **rewrite** your version of Add().

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding the css to myDropdownList and then let CSS do the selecting of the items within the list.  This is how CSS is designed to work.

```
// this Markup    
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDropdownList " runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

// can have a CSS class added on the server like this
this.myDropdownList.Css = "blah";
myDropdownList.Datasource = data;
myDropdownList.DataBind();


// which will render on the page like this
<select class="blah" id="myDropdownList">
     <option>Foobar 1</option> 
     <option>Foobar 2</option> 
     <option>Foobar 3</option> 
</select>


// which you can apply CSS styling to like this
select.blah option {
  flont-size:large;
  color: #aaa;
  font-type:italics;
}
```

Comment: Juls - I have ended up keeping my lines as separate code. I understand what you are saying about letting the CSS handle the work (and agree), but I was trying to apply the class because I am using Bootstrap and trying to apply existing class names defined by Bootstrap.